# Invalid --buffer_pool_limit value, must be a percentage or positive bytes value or percentage: 85%

Tags: docker, impala

I installed an impala server on Docker. But it run failed.

```
`
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319669527Z I0414 02:06:24.506655    18 HiveMetaStoreClient.java:308] HMS client filtering is enabled.
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319673363Z I0414 02:06:24.506819    18 HiveMetaStoreClient.java:472] Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://localhost:9083
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319677337Z I0414 02:06:24.507915    18 HiveMetaStoreClient.java:546] Opened a connection to metastore, current connections: 17
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319681358Z I0414 02:06:24.509375    18 HiveMetaStoreClient.java:599] Connected to metastore.
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319685216Z I0414 02:06:24.510401    18 scheduler.cc:79] Starting scheduler
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319689574Z I0414 02:06:24.510444    18 exec-env.cc:305] Initializing impalad with backend uuid: b54b4db6d7d31965:26c5236244323882
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319695988Z I0414 02:06:24.511391    18 exec-env.cc:476] System memory available: 1.95 GB (from physical mem)
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319723737Z I0414 02:06:24.511713    18 exec-env.cc:499] Using process memory limit: 1.56 GB (--mem_limit=80% of 1.95 GB)
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319730006Z F0414 02:06:24.520639    18 impalad-main.cc:73] Invalid --buffer_pool_limit value, must be a percentage or positive bytes value or percentage: 85%
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319736243Z . Impalad exiting.`
```

Does anyone have a idea to solvev it? I really want to run impala server On Docker successfully.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have sovled this problem by scaling the memory to `16G`. The key information:

```
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319723737Z I0414 02:06:24.511713    18 exec-env.cc:499] Using process memory limit: 1.56 GB (--mem_limit=80% of 1.95 GB)
2023-04-14T02:06:25.319730006Z F0414 02:06:24.520639    18 impalad-main.cc:73] Invalid --buffer_pool_limit value, must be a percentage or positive bytes value or percentage: 85%.
```

The reason is that the memory is too small to run the impalad program.